# Where's Polygon.Double in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

Once again I'm doing Java graphics (Graphics2D) but I noticed there is no Polygon.Double or Polygon.Float classes whereas there is Rectangle2D.Float and Rectangle2D.Double class.

Does anyone know why this is? I just need to draw a triangle using doubles as points.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a [`Path2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) (or a `Path2D.Float` or `Path2D.Double`) to get the same effect.

Comment: Thanks. I also need to fill this polygon. Is this possible with Path2D?

Comment: Yes. `Graphics2D` has a `fill(Shape)` method and `Path2D` is-a `Shape`.