# Java- Use two double arrays as inputs for the constructor "Polygon" to use the method "contains"

Tags: java, arrays, double, polygon, contains

I was wondering if there is any sort of Polygon.double because I need to input two double [] arrays and test whether another point is contained in the polygon.  I saw another post about Path2D.double but it doesn't seem to have any similar methods like "contains" in Polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [contains(double x, double y)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains%28double,%20double%29) in Polygon and Path2D.Double.

EDIT:

Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377551/wheres-polygon-double-in-java).

Comment: Sorry ya I know about that my real problem is that I would like my input arrays into Polygon to be double arrays rather than integer arrays

Comment: Can't you use Path2D.Double to achieve it?

Comment: but I can't seem to find a method similar to contains(double x, double y) in Path2D.Double

Comment: @bryan Path2D.Double exitends Path2D which has `contains(double, double)` Check out the section "Methods inherited from class java.awt.geom.Path2D" in [Path2D.Double](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html)

Comment: @bryan so you should be able to create a new instance of Path2D.Double, use lineTo() to complete the polygon and call contains()